# Path issue in wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

We are having some issue with our relative path in wordpress.
Earlier our application was like http://www.skill-guru.com/skill .
So if we type the blog address as http://www.skill-guru.com/blog it would add a **/** at end and open it as
http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/
Now our application opens as root in domain http://www.skill-guru.com.
Our blog is opening as http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/ but not as http://www.skill-guru.com/blog.
I am not able to understand the reason.
because of this issue , search is also not working.
Can anyone please help me understand what has changed and how it can be fixed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the underlying cause, but while you figure that out you may just want to redirect "blog" to "blog/" in your .htaccess file. I think this will do it...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/blog$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

I'm assuming that somewhere else in the .htaccess you have...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

In fact, you might find that in the process of changing you site someone nuked the existing .htaccess.

Comment: There have been changes to existing .htaccess and I guess that might have caused the problem. I will try these changes to .htaccess. Thanks

Comment: Greg, you are awesome. This works man ! This re write condition I had to write in the blog folder instead of root folder. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

If I visit http://www.skill-guru.com/blog, I get the error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /blog
>
> type Status report
>
> message /blog
>
> description The requested resource
>   (/blog) is not available. Apache
>   Tomcat/6.0.16

This implies that there might be url-rewriting in place or server configuration does not allow you to strip the trailing backslash, you should consult with server support theam.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no server support team. I think the developers nuked the .htaccess as Greg has pointed out.